# Compiler error when calling Windows API with correct parameters

Tags: delphi

I am trying to run this elementary function but it will not work :

```
function GetWindowsUserName: String;
  const
    MAX_LENGTH = 256;
  var
    UserNameLength: DWord;
  begin
    UserNameLength := MAX_LENGTH - 1;
    SetLength(Result, MAX_LENGTH);
    if GetUserName(PChar(Result), UserNameLength) then
      SetLength(Result, UserNameLength - 1)
    else
      Result := '';
  end;
```

On formCreate I have :

```
AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := GetWindowsUserName;
```

I get :

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(115): E2034 Too many actual parameters
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(115): E2012 Type of expression must be BOOLEAN
```

What am I missing here ?

Edit : I am still getting the error :
[image]

Comment: Tags are meant to provide information. Please don't add random tags. If you want to indicate which delphi version you are using do so. Don't tag with 4 versions.

Comment: Put `Windows.` before `GetUserName`.

Comment: I have Winapi.Windows in 'uses' but still get the error.[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(114): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Windows'

Comment: Then try `Winapi.Windows.GetUserName()`.

Comment: @user763539 Why did you even try what Whome suggested. The compiler told you that you had passed too many parameters. Your code passes two, and Whome's passes two. So clearly you'd have the exact same problem. When you are confronted with a compiler error, read it. Try to understand it. Try to relate it to the code. Don't just try things at random.

Comment: The `lp` prefix seems a bit odd assigned to a char buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you report a compiler error, you must indicate which line of the code the error applies to. In this case, the only line of code that can report that error is the call to `GetUserName`.

The only way in which the call to `GetUserName` could fail in that way would be for there to be an unexpected `GetUserName` in scope. Your code expects to find the `GetUserName` defined in the `Windows`. Clearly a different version is in scope.

You can fully specify the symbol to make the compiler use the right one:

```
Windows.GetUserName
```

or if you are using namespaces:

```
Winapi.Windows.GetUserName
```

Comment: Winapi.Windows.GetUserName(@lpUserName, nSize); This did it ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, StdCtrls;
- - - - - - 

{ Get current username. }
function TForm1.GetCurrentUser(): String;
var
   lpUserName: array[0..256] of Char;
   nSize: DWord;
begin
   // Get current loginname
   nSize := SizeOf(lpUserName);
   GetUserName(@lpUserName, nSize);
   Result := lpUserName;
end;
```

Its this function you must use, maybe Uses imports give you something else but similar name. But this is oldskool method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

New method is SSPI interface. (scrap this sspi is actually authenticating user+pwd values against WinAD. GetuserName is fine just reading active windows identity)
http://www.michael-puff.de/Programmierung/Delphi/Units/SSPIValidatePassword.pas

Comment: If two parameters was too many for the code in the question, it will still be too many here.